# Mapping fields as key-value pair

Tags: java, json, jackson

When reading a JSON file, i would like to map my class as follows:

```
public class Effect {
    private final String type;
    private final Map<String, String> parameters;

    public Effect(String type, Map<String, String> parameters) {
        this.type = type;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParameters() {
        return this.parameters;
    }
}
```

```
{
    "type": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2", 
    }
}
```

So, the mapped JSON object consists of `type` as the only key and `parameters` as its value.

I would like to use `@JsonCreator` on the constructor, but can't figure out, how to map the fields. Do i need to write a custom deserializer or is there an easier way to map the class like i want?

---

I wrote a custom deserializer, which does what i want, but there might be an easier way, maybe with annotations alone, which i would like to know:

```
public class EffectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Effect> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public EffectDeserializer() {
        super(Effect.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Effect deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
        Iterator<String> fieldNames = node.fieldNames();
        if(fieldNames.hasNext()) {
            String type = fieldNames.next();
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            for(Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = node.get(type).fields(); fields.hasNext(); ) {
                Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
                parameters.put(field.getKey(), field.getValue().textValue());
            }
            return new Effect(type, parameters);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Another way i found would be adding a `JsonCreator` (constructor in this case), that takes a `Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>` and uses that to initialize the values, like this:

```
@JsonCreator
public Effect(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry) {
    this.type = entry.getKey();
    this.parameters = entry.getValue();
}
```

If there's no way to get it done with a "normal" constructor, i will probably end up using this, as it uses Jackson's default mapping for `Map.Entry`, reducing possible error margin.

Comment: You are defining `type` as a `String` - how do you expect JSON mapper to know it is something else? - It seems to me you want to rename your `parameters` (call it `type`) and get rid of the `String` definition of `type`

Comment: I only used `type` as an example. There could be any String in its place, which i would like to get mapped to the String field.

Comment: The name of the parameter is what becomes the attribute (key) name when mapped to JSON. You may have to re-think your approach

Comment: I edited the OP and added a custom deserializer, which does what i want. I would just like to know, if there's an easier (or more standard) way to do this.

Comment: are those two fields the only ones to map? (i.e. or worry about?)

Comment: Yes, the class basically represents a `Map.Entry` (see latest edit).

Comment: OK, the only way I could get it to work was doing (what seems to be) a workaround. perhaps it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a static factory method that accepts a `Map` with a dynamic key:

```
@JsonCreator
public static Effect create(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {
    String type = map.keySet().iterator().next();
    return new Effect(type, map.get(type));
}
```

EDIT: Just noticed this is basically an uglier version of your own solution using `Map.Entry`. I would go with that instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's about what i ended up using. I used a `Map.Entry`, instead, as you noted in your edit, as it gets rid of the iterator call and enforces that there is only 1 key in the JSON object.